# How to know current Email governor limits?

Tags: apex, email, governorlimits, limits, apex-email-service

I am using SingleEmailMessage api for sending emails. I want to know the email limit quota usage, so that I can prevent further exceptions. Is there any way to know the quota usage in apex, so that I can handle exception with ease.

Comment: See also: [single email limit exceeded salesforce very frequently..?](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/17133/single-email-limit-exceeded-salesforce-very-frequently/17140#17140).

Comment: This post should not be closed, it is asking a completely different question. There is also a better way to check for limits using the `System.OrgLimits` class 

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_class_System_OrgLimits.htm

Comment: @jitender-padda Consider posting your answer here as well if this is reopened

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `Limits` [class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.198.0.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_limits.htm#apex_System_Limits_getLimitEmailInvocations) to find out how many invocations remain as follows:

```
Integer remainingInvocations =
    Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations() - Limits.getEmailInvocations();
```

Comment: That only gives you the limits for the current transaction.

Comment: @sfdcfox That's why I linked to another question in the comments. Pretty sure this question has been answered in a couple different spots but didn't spot a definitive dupe off the bat.

Answer (score 2):

A strategy to use would be the following (assuming your APEX is sending one (1) email message; adapt code for more than one accordingly. The key is the method `Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(someInteger)` that you invoke before you send.

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage email = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
try {
        Messaging.reserveSingleEmailCapacity(1); // SFDC throws exception if no headroom
        email.setToAddresses(...);
        ...
        Messaging.sendEmail(email);
}
catch (HandledException e) {
// do something interesting like set up a retry mechanism for the next day
// by persisting the message to send in some object and then having a daily
// scheduled job resend the message at 0000h
}
```

There is [a related post on this topic](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/17140/2602) by @DougB

> UPDATE
>
> Prior to Winter 14, the `reserveMassEmailCapacity` existed but would
>   throw an unhandled exception, this changed as per the Winter 14
>   Release Notes page 304
>
> Updated Errors for Email Messaging Methods Errors have changed for the
>   Apex Messaging methods reserveMassEmailCapacity and
>   reserveSingleEmailCapacity, which are used when sending a mass or
>   single email, respectively. If the transaction would cause the
>   organization to exceed its daily email limit, using either of these
>   methods results in a Handled Exception error. (Previously it resulted
>   in a Limit Exception error.) The error that appears is:
>   System.HandledException: The daily limit for the org would be exceeded
>   by this request.

Comment: It looks like the exception from `reserveSingleEmailCapacity` is [uncatchable](https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aSLLAA2). That's the answer I linked in the comments. :)

Comment: @adrianLarson see my update above

Comment: How long is the capacity "reserved" for? Just the transaction context? The full 24 hours?

Comment: At most I would think it was the transaction

Comment: OP totally accepted the wrong answer on this one. Oops.