# Query email limits in Apex code

Tags: apex, governorlimits, email-alert, singleemailmessage

I have a requirement to send emails to external users using apex code , but the email limit is 5000 per day using single email messaging class.

I am using a batch job to send email , but before I get the number of records to whom I need to send email I want to know how much is the email limit left for today. Is there way to query the limit in apex code to check how much email limit is left for a day?

Comment: Actually, that is the wrong duplicate. In that question, the OP had a problem where he was making too many sendEmail calls within a context. In this case, the OP has a problem with the daily limit

Comment: @SebastianKessel Hmm, the answer there seems to contain the answer to this question as I read it. Do you think there is a different dupe out there or that this is a new question?

Comment: It does, but on a tangential way. The question doesn't ask for it. A casual reader might not see the nuance or the difference between both answers.

Comment: And this has been asked by the OP before. http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/143961/best-way-to-send-mass-email-from-salesforce-to-external-email-ids

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATED ANSWER:

Turns out, the `Limits` class is now what you need. I'll go back to what I used to do.

You can use `Messaging.reserveMassEmailCapacity(count);`. This call will result in an error if you don't have enough capacity. It's not exactly what you asked, but it could do the trick in your case.

Reference: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_forcecom_email_outbound.htm

Also, vote the idea that would expose this limit via the class above: https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000aSLLAA2

Comment: Nope. That gives you the current context limit, not the daily limit.

Comment: Damnit. Why don't I properly read my own links?

Comment: Also the OP totally accepted the wrong answer [here](http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/104888/how-to-know-current-email-governor-limits) after I made the same mixup.

Comment: I am glad I am not the only one.... the solution I outlined might help him.

Comment: Actually, @AdrianLarson that is the wrong duplicate. In that question, the OP had a problem where he was making too many `sendEmail` calls within a context. In this case, the OP has a problem with the daily limit.

Comment: In execute anonymous I tried executing - system.debug('*******' + Messaging.reserveMassEmailCapacity(count)); and I get - Variable does not exist: count    AND when I use system.debug('***' + Limits.getLimitEmailInvocations()) I get output as 10. Why do I get 10 instead of 5000, which is the daily email limit using apex code? Any idea?

Comment: That `Limits` method returns how many times you can call `Messaging.sendEmail`, which is indeed 10. You should replace `count` with the number of emails to verify.

Comment: Can I not call sendEmail more than 10 times in a for loop? I will be using send email method in a batch class and use send email with different email addresses(around 500 email address). I will be using sendemail in a for loop.

Comment: You can call `sendEmail` once on a `List` that contains 5000 emails.

Comment: ....Assuming you have a 5000 emails available to send.

Comment: @SebastianKessel Can I use Messaging.reserveMassEmailCapacity(count); in execute anonymous to check what I get? I tried Messaging.reserveMassEmailCapacity(10); but did not work in exe anonymous

Comment: What does "did not work" mean?

Comment: @SebastianKessel when i executed - system.debug('***********' + Messaging.reserveMassEmailCapacity(10)); in exe anonymous , I got an error - Line: 1, Column: 14
Arithmetic expressions are not allowed on void types.

Comment: As its incorrectly merged, adding my findings here, I also faced it and was able to get it from Metadata API

Salesforce Article Link: https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000331939&type=1

API: GET: /services/data/v53.0/limits
IN Result Check for SingleEmail or MassEmail based on your need