# How can be avoided error SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED Email limit exceeded if need to send email to one single user?

Tags: governorlimits, limits

I have been looking for some time looking for a way how can error SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED Email limit exceeded be avoided if I need to send one simple email to one single user, for example, myself.

15 Email invocations limit on Developer Edition is a very small number, and it is usually quickly exceeded. Using Workflow Email Alerts may help to send more emails but still it is limited.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Looks like I have found an answer very long time back but didn't write it down.
So today I started investigating this again and decided to store the solution found somewhere.

It is interesting that this documentation has a small sentence answering this question.
https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000002490&language=en_US

> Emails sent using setTargetObjectId() set against the user object do
>   not count against the SingleEmailMessage limit.

It is very interesting that if I run this code

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setToAddresses( new List<String>{'julfy@i.ua'} );
mail.setSubject( 'test 2' );
mail.setHtmlBody( 'test 2' );
Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail } );
```

it fails with error

> Line: 14, Column: 1 System.EmailException: SendEmail failed. First
>   exception on row 0; first error: SINGLE_EMAIL_LIMIT_EXCEEDED, Email
>   limit exceeded: []

while if I execute the code

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage mail = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
mail.setTargetObjectId( UserInfo.getUserId() );
mail.setSaveAsActivity( false );
mail.setSubject( 'test 2' );
mail.setHtmlBody( 'test 2' );
Messaging.sendEmail( new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage[] { mail } );
```

I see no errors.

Looks like someone else also has mentioned this here:
https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/17143/3716

However, that answer is undervoted and doesn't appear on the top on googling.

Comment: Are you referring to @Ashwani answer to that question or to the accepted answer? If you copy the link on the "share" button, you get a link to the specific answer you're referring to for the question. I show a different link that what you've posted, even though yours takes me to his answer is why I ask.

Comment: I meant Ashwani answer, not the accepted one

Comment: @crmprogdev I meant Ashwani answer, and I believe I have put the correct link: http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/17143/3716